# Facebook Post Like action not working in Android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am using facebook sdk for login in android app. my code working fine for login facebook in android app. but then i used facebook like action using facebook sdk error is occured. The error is below

```
{Response:  responseCode: 403, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action}, isFromCache:false}}, isFromCache:false}
```

And the code is:-

```
String grapPath = String.format("%s/likes", postID);
        Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), grapPath,
                null, HttpMethod.POST, new Request.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        String res = response.toString();
                        Log.i("********************************", res
                                + " Success!");
                    }
                });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Please help me for solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error is quite clear , you do not have the required permission to post ,
while logging the user , ask for the relevant permission "publish_actions"

For more info --> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

Comment: if you request this permission , facebook will need to review your app on how your app uses this permission.